# What does this chart mean when it says "lbs per round" or "lbs per sqare/rectangle"?

Tags: cake, cooking-time

From http://howtocakeit.com/blogs/cakes/48185153-how-to-make-ice-and-decorate-yo-yo-s-chocolate-cake-like-a-pro:

[image: http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0759/4297/files/How_To_Cake_It_Orange_Velvet_Baking_Chart_large.png?8150771157822701686]

What do the different columns mean?

Comment: The general layout of that table is really terrible.

Comment: "Per round" or "per square/rectangle" - if you want to make two or more layers, it's assumed you'd use the same shaped pan, so that's the amount of a single layer in a single pan.

Answer (score 11):

It is a scalable recipe. First, you decide in which pan you want to bake the cake. You take your pan and measure it. Let's say you have a 9" round pan. You go into the column "lbs per round" and find out that your pan takes 3 1/2 lbs of batter. Then you go to the other table with ingredients measurements, multiply the column "6 lbs" by 7/12, and have your ingredient measurements. Alternatively, you can bake a slightly thinner cake, and divide the amounts in the 6 lbs cake by 2.

Alternatively, if you want the tall kind of cake shown in the pictures, first decide what amount you want to bake, then use the table to calculate how many pans you will need to get that amount of batter baked. For example, for a 8 lb cake with a square base, you could use 4 6" square pans.

When you have made your batter, the last column tells you how much time you should expect, roughly, for the cake to bake through. For the 9" round cake, it would be 1 hour 10 min. Don't forget that this is only an estimate, you should take the cake out when it is done, not when the timer goes off.

Comment: The weird thing is how the measurements don't add up with basic geometry here. You'd expect the batter for a cake of double the radius to require 4 times the batter not six times.

Comment: The whole recipe is not about precision. So it's not that strange if it produces layers of different thickness. It's more of a guideline for a cook who wonders how many pans to prep.

Answer (score -2):

Just measure across the pan.  If the pan is round then use the round column.  If the pan is square then use the square column.  Baking time is exactly that.

If the pan is not square (and not round) then not perfect but use the average.  So for a 5 x 7 rectangle then use 6.

Comment: The question specifically asks what lbs/round or square means. This doesn't address that at all.

Comment: @Jolenealaska It asks what the columns mean.

Comment: The title specifically asks about the columns you did not address in the answer.

Comment: @Jolenealaska Thanks for the feedback.  Is it possible to have more than one valid interpretation of a question?

Comment: Of course it is possible, but I don't think that is the case here. The other columns seem quite obvious, whereas the lbs per seem less so. I don't intend to delete your answer, but I don't think it's a very good one.